# Inconsistent behaviour of Jackson's JsonFormat for Old Date API and ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, serialization, jackson, zoneddatetime

I was trying to use Jackson's JsonFormat annotation in my ***POJO*** class to serialize the ZonedDateTime into a different timezone. (Say the timezone in ZonedDateTimeZone is ET, I want to serialize it in UTC)

**My POJO:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class POJO {


    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone = "UTC")
    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeWithPatternAndTimeZoneInJsonFormat;

    @JsonFormat(timezone = "UTC")
    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeWithTimeZoneInJsonFormat;

    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime;


    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone = "UTC")
    private Date oldDateWithTimeZoneAndPatternInJsonFormat;

    @JsonFormat(timezone = "UTC")
    private Date oldDateWithTimeZoneInJsonFormat;

    private Date oldDate;

    //  getters and setters below


}
```

**Main Method**

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.TimeZone;

package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

//@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.JUNE.getValue(), 12, 15, 0 , 0);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        Date oldDate = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());

        System.out.println("old Date with System's time zone" + oldDate);

        POJO pojo = new POJO();
        pojo.setOldDate(oldDate);
        pojo.setOldDateWithTimeZoneAndPatternInJsonFormat(oldDate);
        pojo.setOldDateWithTimeZoneInJsonFormat(oldDate);

        pojo.setZonedDateTimeWithPatternAndTimeZoneInJsonFormat(zdt);
        pojo.setZonedDateTimeWithTimeZoneInJsonFormat(zdt);
        pojo.setZonedDateTime(zdt);

        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo));

    }


}
```

**Output:**

```
old Date with System's time zoneSat Jun 13 00:30:00 IST 2020

{
    "zonedDateTimeWithPatternAndTimeZoneInJsonFormat": "2020-06-12 19:00:00.000+0000",
    "zonedDateTimeWithTimeZoneInJsonFormat": "2020-06-12T15:00:00-04:00",
    "zonedDateTime": "2020-06-12T15:00:00-04:00",
    "oldDateWithTimeZoneAndPatternInJsonFormat": "2020-06-12 19:00:00.000+0000",
    "oldDateWithTimeZoneInJsonFormat": "2020-06-12T19:00:00.000+00:00",
    "oldDate": "2020-06-13T00:30:00.000+05:30"
}
```

As you can see in output, if i only specify timezone and not pattern, the oldDateWithTimeZone is serialized in UTC timezone but for ZonedDateTime only specifying timezone doesn't serialize it in specified timezone. But if you specify pattern as well, It respects the specified timezone.

Comment: @Miaden - Edited my code,  Due to the misunderstanding in different formats,  I tried to use the pattern property to have zonedDateTime and oldDate to have the same format. While doing so, I realized, that specifying timezone only for oldDate serializes it in specified timezone, but for ZonedDateTime, it requires pattern and timezone both. Weird!

Comment: Reported issue on https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's an issue in jackson-databind. Reported the issue on https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2799 .

As mentioned in question's comments section, Specifying timezone along with pattern, i.e. `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone = "UTC")` works as expected. I earlier tried just with timezone.

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonFormat(timezone= "UTC")` sets your timezone when serializing date, not format.
If you want to change format i suggest using

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
```

With implementation of `CustomDateSerializer`

```
class CustomDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<ZonedDateTime> {


public CustomDateSerializer(Class<ZonedDateTime> t) {
    super(t);
}

public CustomDateSerializer() {
    this(null);
}

@Override
public void serialize(ZonedDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    LocalDateTime utc = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(value.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    gen.writeString("##date format here##");
}}
```

Comment: My bad here, I don't want to change the format, I want to serialize the date in UTC time zone.

Comment: Top of the head but you can convert first to utc time then serialize it. (edited implementation)

Comment: @Miaden, yes I could do that, but the use case here is to convert the entity classes to different DTOs (most of them wanting Date in different timezone.) Using JsonFormat can reduce lots of boilerplate

Comment: Sorry for typo while specifying user.